# AVPlayer not playing URL from backend

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to play URL's i'm fetching from my backend.  Initially, I was downloading the items to my documents directory and used the urls to play the files via `AVAudioPlayer`.  I switched over to `AVPlayer` so I can stream the audio instead of downloading them.  I see that the URL's are being fetched successfully, but once I try to play them I get no audio.  Below is an example of a URL i'm fetching:

/Users/ellie/Desktop/ellie/sound/uploads/ellie1/Track5.m4a

```
var player: AVPlayer!
var fetchedURL: NSURL?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //I left out the fetching process
    self.fetchedURL = NSURL(string:parseString!)
    print("fetchedURL is \(self.fetchedURL!)")
    self.playCell()
}

func playCell() {

    let audioSession: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch _ {
    }

    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
    }

    print("fetchedURL is \(self.fetchedURL!)")
    player = AVPlayer(URL:self.fetchedURL!)
    player.play()
}
```

Comment: "I switched over to AVPlayer so I can stream the audio instead of downloading them" where is the live streaming url?
/Users/ellie/Desktop/ellie/sound/uploads/ellie1/Track5.m4a this one doesn't look like neither any one else can help you with this url.

Comment: NSURL(string:) is for web links only.  for local resourse path you need to use NSURL(fileURLWithPath:) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:

Comment: Why dont you just use try? Or try! Instead of "do try catch_"

Comment: My backend is all local, but I thought that since I'm accessing files from the server I still have to treat the Url as a web link

Answer (score 1):

The AVPlayer will play only locally and remotely hosted video files, and will also play streaming links. To stream you need to ensure that a proper streaming link is used, some examples found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104301/hls-streaming-video-url-need-for-testing.

Note, that it is not a trivial task to convert a video file into a hosted streaming link. Services such as vimeo provide the ability to upload and encode video files, however will provide you with a streaming link only under the 'pro' version.

Other options include configure AWS S3 buckets to host and encode your video files. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingJWPlayer.html